# Getting windows registry editor version

Tags: c#, regedit

I'm creating an app which should get entire .reg file and then execute it.
The registry keys are created by me, my installer works on win XP, 7 and 8.
But if I change registry file header to `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00` 
executing failed on windows XP. This error occurs whenever I change OS and header to another version.

My reg file looks like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 //- here is my problem

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyApp\myApp]
"DisplayName"="myApp"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyApp2\myFile]
"Directory"="C:\\myFile"
```

I am interested in .reg file executing only without `Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey` or similar.
Is it standard behavior or I am missing something?
Is there some way to retrieve Windows Registry Editor version from C# code?

I'm working with windows 7 in example above.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: XP questions require psychic debugging.  Version 5.00 is the version number of Windows 2000 so unlikely to be the issue.  The text encoding of the .reg file might matters, it is always utf-16 for a .reg file with that header.  It will be utf-8 however if you edited it with Visual Studio.  File + Save As, click the arrow on the Save button to change the encoding.  3rd in the list (1200).  Do us all a favor and stop supporting XP.

Comment: Registry editor version depends on the windows version. I think the best solution is get the windows version and calculate the registry editor version by your self. You can use "System.OperatingSystem os = System.Environment.OSVersion;" to get the windows version.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, a .reg file should have the following syntax:

```
RegistryEditorVersion
Blank line
[RegistryPath1] 
"DataItemName1"="DataType1:DataValue1"
DataItemName2"="DataType2:DataValue2"
Blank line
[RegistryPath2] 
"DataItemName3"="DataType3:DataValue3"
Blank line
```

In Windows 2000 and later, the file begins with "Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00" (so that line should not make troubles), while earlier versions began with "REGEDIT4".

So make sure you have the right .reg file format (with **Blank lines**!), and try to use **System.Text.Encoding.Unicode** encoding while reading your files.

Comment: The poster is using that format, and has mentioned that the problem is with Windows **XP**, which predates Windows 2000 and uses the REGEDIT4 format. The poster is also not *reading* the files, so the information about Encoding.Unicode is irrelevant here.